# HTML5/AngularJS: How can you have an autocomplete list hold object values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

script.js

```
function loadItems() {
    var data = [ 
        { name: 'Chicken', id: '7777' },
        { name: 'Corn', id: '9001' },
        { name: 'Cabbage', id: '6996' },
        { name: 'Chili', id: '4242' },
        { name: 'Cheese', id: '1337' }
    ];
    sessionStorage.setItem( 'items', JSON.stringify(data) );
}

function TypeaheadCtrl( $scope, $http ) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items'));
}
```

index.html

```
<body onload='init()'>
    <div id='container' ng-controller='TypeaheadCtrl'>
        <h4 class="ng-binding">Item Name: {{itemName}}</h4>
        <h4 class="ng-binding">Item Id: 7777</h4>
        <input id='itemInput' type="text" ng-model="itemName" placeholder="Item Name" typeahead="item.name for item in items | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's more of the code I'm using: http://plnkr.co/edit/sqcbYIkhy29hq8TyiHRx

In the link above, I am able to list the objects for the autocomplete list, but only the name of those objects.

What I want is to only display the name of the objects for the list, but when it's selected, store that selected object's id somewhere else for usage. Unfortunately, it's only a list of object names, not objects.

[image]

What I want.

[image]

Comment: Didnt this fiddle help you ? http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need bind to ng-model as object instead of text

```
<h3 class="ng-binding">Item Name: {{item.name}}</h3>
<h3 class="ng-binding">Item Id: ({{item.id}})</h3>
<input id='itemInput' type="text" ng-model="item" placeholder="Item Name" typeahead="item as item.name for item in items | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control">
```

Another thing is the typeahead expression should change to `item as item.name for item in items` to allow bind to model.

I updated the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/ski53kuM5oJA21x0MO8O?p=preview

You also can refer to http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (under Typeahead section) . Look for customSelected example. It do exactly what you want.

Comment: Holy crap! You're a savior! Thank you soooooo much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in the controller to get this.

See plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/sN6Adnj7kIrGXJ5QyWjN?p=info

Markup:

```
<h3 class="ng-binding">Item Id: {{ getId(itemName) }}</h3>


$scope.getId = function (name) {
  var response = '';

  $scope.items.forEach(function (d) {
    if(d.name === name) {
     response = d.id;
    }
  })
  return response;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would work if all of those object's name are unique, but what if there are names that are the same? Then this wouldn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: what id should be returned in the scenario where there are 2 names that are the same?

Comment: Yeah, like if there are two items named 'corn', but from different companies, it'll have different ids. Since the corn is an object, it holds an id with it. Which ever corn you select, it should give you its id.